# How to close only subwindow when use closeEvent for X button?

Tags: c++, qt, function

I use method `closeEvent` for X button on the top right in the interface.

[image: window]

The requirements are:

- when I click "Close" -> both windows (Exit and MainWindow) will be closed.
- when I click "Cancel"-> only "Exit" windows will be closed, MainWindow still stays there.

But when I click on "Cancel", both windows are closed -> how to solve this problem?

How to move button "Cancel" in between "Save" and "Close"

[image: dialog]

This is my code

myclass.h

```
class MyClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(QcgDatabase* db, int hostid, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyClass();

public slots:
    void save_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MyClass ui;
    QMessageBox* dialog = NULL;
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *bar);
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass(QcgDatabase * db, int hostid, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    .......
    .......
}

void MyClass::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *bar)
{
    if (!dialog) {
        dialog = new QMessageBox(this);
    }
    dialog->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    dialog->setWindowTitle(QLatin1String("Exit"));
    dialog->setText(QLatin1String("You have not saved data. Click \"Close\" to close the data table."));
    dialog->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::Close);

    int result = dialog->exec();
    if (result == QMessageBox::Save) {
        save_clicked();
    }
    else if (result == QMessageBox::Cancel) {
        dialog->close();
        return;
    }
    else if (result == QMessageBox::Close) {
        dialog->close();
    }

    bar->accept();
}
```

Edit:

ok, i fixed the problem with window:

```
 else if (result == QMessageBox::Cancel) {
    bar->ignore();
    return;
 }
```

Please help me to swap position of buttons "Close" and "Cancel"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `if (result == QMessageBox::Cancel)` branch it is not enough to close only your dialog. You also need to call [`QEvent::ignore()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qevent.html#ignore) on the event object:

```
bar->ignore()
```

This is because your `MyClass::closeEvent` is called only to give you chance to do something when window is about to be closed, but event itself will continue its journey in the labyrinth of Qt framework and eventualy will cause window to be closed - unless you mark it to be ignored

Comment: thanks, I have just found it at the same time also. Could you help me to swap position of "Close" and "Cancel"?

Comment: I am affraid it is not possible using `StandardButtons`, You'll need to design your dialog yourself placing buttons one by one to desired positions

Comment: thank you, yeah maybe I need to design a new dialog. I have an easy solution `dialog->setButtonText(QMessageBox::Close,"Cancel");
    dialog->setButtonText(QMessageBox::Cancel,"Close");`  But it looks so weird ))))

Comment: BTW, from UI design point of view, I don't think it is good idea to swap position of "Close" and "Cancel" - you will break existing consistency of standard buttons layout

Comment: yeah, after discussion, I decide to leave it like standard. Thanks !